# mpi & number of processor

Tags: visual-studio-2019, mpi, codeblocks

hello i'm using windows  and i use both codeblock & visual studio 2019 to programm using  mpi.
but  after i use this code

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int rank, size;

    MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);

    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &rank);
    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &size);

    printf("Hello world! I am %d of %d\n", rank, size);

    MPI_Finalize();

    return 0;
}
```

it return me 1 processor while if use echo %NUMBER_OF_PROCESSORS%
on normal cmd it return me 4 .

i was using MPI_SEND & MPI_Recv and i had a A FATAL ERROR AFTER USING THIS CODE

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "mpi.h"

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    int menum, nproc;
    int n, tag, num;
    MPI_Status info;
    MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &menum);
    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &nproc);
    printf("menum:%d      nproc :%d", menum, nproc);
    if (menum == 0) {
        printf("\ninsert number: ");
        scanf_s(" %d", &n);
        tag = 10;
        MPI_Send(&n, 1, MPI_INT, 1, tag, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    }
    else {
        tag = 10;
        MPI_Recv(&n, 1, MPI_INT, 0, tag, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &info);
    }
    MPI_Get_count(&info, MPI_INT, &num);
    MPI_Finalize();
    return 0;
}
```

i searched online  and as i could understand it's like  mpi cant find another processor to send the value.
how can i  make it??
is there a way i could use mpi with all my processor  with visual studio  or codeblock?

job aborted:
[ranks] message

[0] fatal error
Fatal error in MPI_Send: Invalid rank, error stack:
MPI_Send(buf=0x0056F9F0, count=1, MPI_INT, dest=1, tag=10, MPI_COMM_WORLD) failed
Invalid rank has value 1 but must be nonnegative and less than 1

Comment: How are you launching these jobs? Sounds like Singleton init happening here.

Comment: ctrl + f5  this is always what i do :/

Answer (score 1):

If you write an MPI program and just execute it directly you get what's called `singleton init` -- The MPI library will start itself up and you get one process in `MPI_COMM_WORLD`.

To launch a parallel MPI program on Windows, you'll need to consult your MPI implementation.  For MS-MPI, you will use the `HPC Job Manager` (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/high-performance-computing/overview?view=hpc19-ps)  .

For Intel-MPI you go through a similar process constructing a host file and registering your windows credentials with each machine (https://software.intel.com/content/www/us/en/develop/documentation/mpi-developer-guide-windows/top.htm)

I don't have any experience with MPI on Windows machines so this is as much help as I can give you.  Hope it gets you pointed in the right direction.

Comment: I have a mpi code. I got error at runtime. Can you please take a look https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71200986/try-to-convert-c-program-to-mpi-program-but-error-occur